# Struts: Multiple time execution in JSP page

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jstl, struts

I have tried to run following code in struts and getting error as:

```jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> <!DOCTYPE
        HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">         
<html> 
<jsp:include page="/Shop_login.jsp"></jsp:include>
<head>Welcome To My shop application </head> 
<body> 
  User Name:<html:input text="first_name"> </html:input>
  Password:<html:password text="password"> </html:password>  
</body>
</html>
```

getting output as:

```
Welcome To My shop application User Name: Password: Welcome To My shop application User Name: Password: Welcome To My shop application User Name: Password: Welcome To My shop application User Name: Password:  ...
```

Comment: The JSP page above is not Shop_login.jsp, is it?

Comment: Sorry,I found my mistake.I have included 'Shop_login.jsp' instead of including 'Struts_lib.jsp'.Thank you!!

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What's the name of the JSP containing the above code? And what does Shop_login.jsp contain? Also, show us the real code of the JSP (I doubt you have "enter code here" in the actual JSP). You're using struts tags without declaring the struts taglib at the top of the JSP.

Comment: @Nizet: My struts_lib.jsp conatains basic tag libs for struts:<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld" prefix="nested" %>
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles"%> now my code is working  fine.previously i had include wrong file.

Comment: @Nizet: I am not getting helping tags(ctrl+space) in ecilipse for struts. can you help me??

Comment: Declare the taglibs in the JSPs using them, instead of declaring them in a dynamically included JSP which, BTW, will make the generated HTML invalid. Drop this Struts_lib.jsp page.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.It is working fine now.My idea was create a all taglibs in one jsp page and use that jsp in other jsp which are using struts.Can you please tell me the reason why it is not working wen i am including teh jsp page??

Comment: It would work if the page was *statically* included (i.e. with `<%@ include %>`). But even then, Eclipse would probably not figure it out and you still wouldn't have code completion.

Answer (score 0):

You could have these taglibs in the JSP, also if you use JSTL

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="bean" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="logic" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" %>
```

nothing more in the file just these fragments of code

then using

```
<%@ include file="/tags/taglibs.jsp" %>
```

at the top of the page, you can use the tags below the definition.
Other JSP fragments you can include with JSTL, for example

```
<c:import url="/pages/page.jsp"/>
```

or using JSP directive

```
<jsp:include page="/pages/page.jsp"/>
```

and don't use the same fragment inside itself, it may cause recursive calls in the servlet compiled from your code.